# Waiting for a specific view on androidviewclient

Tags: androidviewclient

I am using androidviewclient from dtmilano and it works great.

I need to know how do I wait for a specific view to appear on the screen and then take an action ?

I am using getandroidview() but not able to understand its correct implementation.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
...
while True:
    vc.dump()
    if vc.findViewWithText('Hello World!'):
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.ViewNotFoundException: Couldn't find View with ID='com.login:id/next_button' in tree with root=ROOT I am getting this error . HOw to resolve ?

Comment: And it should be vc.findViewWithText() not just findViewWithText(). Although I have used vc.findViewByIdOrRaise()

Comment: If you ask it to raise an exception if not found, well it raises an exception, in such case you could use `try/except`.

Comment: I am new to python, can you edit the above code exactly   so that I could use it.

Comment: Done. The code should work. If you encounter any problem just show the error message.

Comment: raise ViewNotFoundException("ID", viewId, root)
com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.ViewNotFoundException: Couldn't find View with ID='com.login:id/next_button' in tree with root=ROOT Still getting this error

Comment: Code is : while True:
    vc.dump(window='-1')
    if  vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.login:id/next_button"):
        login___id_next_button = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.login:id/next_button")
        login___id_next_button.touch()
        pass
    else:
        time.sleep(3)

Comment: As I mentioned before, if you don't want the method to raise exceptions then don't use the `...OrRaise()` versions.

Comment: I just should use vc.findViewbyID() then ? Is there a so called method ?

Comment: Yes, there is, just check the source if you want to find out what other methods are available.